# How can I play audio files in electron's main process whilst controlling pause/play/seek using the react ui

Tags: audio, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I am working on an electron app ( built on top of electron react ts template that electron provides ) Now I want to be able to play audio files using the app. I want control over seek, play, pause for the audio file. How can I achieve this? I've tried many ways like trying to run audio file on the main process and control it with ipcEvents but that didn't work well. I tried to use Tone js/ play-sound/ speaker all of them had problems. If you know of any approach that can help me in playing audio file and having control over seek/pause/play.